# How to add text dynamically to .html from BASH script?

Tags: html, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a bash script that runs every 5 minutes via cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "`users | wc -w`" users logged on @" `date`" >> /var/www/users.html
```

I need the output text to display in a html page in a single column. I have been using the following HTML code but don't know how to get the output from the script to display properly between the tags dynamically. The script will run and add the output after the HTML code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>2 users logged on @ Fri Jan 16 16:59:01 EST 2015</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 users logged on @ Fri Jan 16 16:59:01 EST 2015</td>
</td>
<tr>
<td>2 users logged on @ Fri Jan 16 16:59:01 EST 2015</td>
</tr>
</table>
2 users logged on @ Fri Jan 16 19:11:02 EST 2015
2 users logged on @ Fri Jan 16 19:12:01 EST 2015
2 users logged on @ Fri Jan 16 19:13:01 EST 2015
2 users logged on @ Fri Jan 16 19:14:01 EST 2015
```

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=$(echo "<td>`users | wc -w`" users logged on @" `date`</td>")
sed -i -e "$ i <tr>" -e "$ i $VAR" -e "$ i </tr>" /var/www/users.html
```

We are using sed to add the content instead of shell redirector.

Comment: +1.  I was going to suggest 1) appending each line to a separate text file, then 2) (re)creating the entire HTML document from the text file contents.  I like your solution a lot better :)

Comment: Is there a way to sort so the higher number of logons are displayed at top of web page? Thank you.